How to Implement Authentication in a Kubernetes-Deployed System on Azure
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I am currently deploying a system on Azure using Kubernetes. The architecture includes two backend services (User Service and Tweet Service) and one frontend service for now. All traffic is routed through an ingress controller. At this stage, the entire setup is functioning correctly, and I can provide an Argo CD dashboard screenshot for clarity.

I am now looking to add authentication to enhance security but need it to be cost-effective and straightforward to implement, considering the project's educational nature. I'm seeking advice on the following points:
Authentication Strategy: Could you recommend some free and simple authentication strategies for Kubernetes services? I'm considering options like OAuth2, JWT, or others suitable for a distributed environment.
Implementation Details: How can these authentication methods be integrated into the existing Kubernetes setup? Are there specific configurations or Kubernetes resources that would facilitate this?
Azure Specifics: Given that the deployment is on Azure, are there Azure services (like Azure Active Directory) that I could leverage for authentication without incurring additional costs? How do they integrate with Kubernetes?
I would appreciate any examples, insights, or resources you could share that would help make this setup both effective and simple. Thank you!

You can use Azure key vault with CSI driver.
Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver
